# YII on different domain

Tags: php, dns, yii, routes

I have two part of application. The first is a manager panel and it is pointed to http://mysite.com/. Other is a personal product page and they are pointed to own domein http://product_domain.com/ . These are parts have two different router maps but common models, components and widgets. The list of all product domain I have saved in database.

**What the best way to separate this parts?**

P.S. Maybe i should have two different application or config?

Answer (score 1):

What we usually do is use a combination of a "prerouter" and modile.

Yii supports this by way of an "onbeginrequest"  => array('Class', 'function') in your config.

In that function you can detect where the user came from and make the needed changes. For example activate a specific module (if all the functionality is grouped in one), or set a different defaultController. Perhaps you want to load a custom theme?

You can do it all in there before anything is done.